# Is it useless to edit a bad question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Does it make any sense to edit a question which I have flagged and will probably be closed?7

An example would be to add the [homework] tag to a bad homework question.

Comment: Probably not, it gives the op an insight of how to ask questions in future in a better way.

Comment: @rijulgupta Isn't that precisely what we're trying to do? Get people to ask questions better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, *always* add the [homework](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework). In fact, I would say always edit the tags on good and bad questions if appropriate. After all, you may flag it but it might not get closed for awhile.

I call my approach to bad [homework](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) specifically the DEF method -- Downvote, Edit, Flag.

Answer (score 9):

It can still be useful for people who come across the question later and may look to it as an example of how to ask their own questions. So I wouldn't call it a bad idea. But it's not as important to edit a question which is going to be closed as it is to edit those which are going to stay open.